# How to retrieve $_COOKIE value?

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm trying to make and keep session for logged users. For that purpose i use table in my database where i want to store user's session data.

Here is part of my createSession() function:

```
...;
if ($result['cnt']){
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $sessionidTHEPROBLEM = md5(rand(-1000,1000).microtime()) . md5(crc32(microtime()).$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    $delete = "delete from session where ID_user = '$result[ID_user]';";
    $insert = "insert into session (ID_user, id, ip, web) values ('$result[ID_user]', '$sessionidTHEPROBLEM', '$ip', '$browser');";

   mysqli_query($db, $delete);
   mysqli_query($db, $insert);

   if (!mysqli_errno($db)){

       setcookie("session", $sessionidTHEPROBLEM);
       echo "logged in";
       header("location:logged.php");


       echo "<br> sessionID send to database: <br>";
       var_dump($sessionidTHEPROBLEM);
       echo "<br> sessionID in cookie: <br>";
       var_dump($_COOKIE["session"]);
    } ...
} ...
```

The result of above var_dump is:

```
sessionID send to database:
string(64) "c96f5ebc3cc6012472b46b4452622328f243f35c93b02e8d929466bcc82fe011"
sessionID in cookie:
string(64) "eb3963230bef2d8ae7ad7c039a40892a1598edcd063233b6ef501c3ff13c1934"
```

And thats my problem. I'm not able to validate the user therefore in logged.php file user is beeing logged out all the time.

Comment: after you set a cookie, it's sent to the browser, so the `$_COOKIE` variable you set will be available the next page load.

Comment: Yep. You guys are right. Didn't notice that after refreshing page $_COOKIE is the same as the value in data base before refresh. Thank you.